# Setting Classpath but Java program(using Apache external jar) doesnt run on CMD Line

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, cmd

So I followed a couple of tutorials and I am basically trying to run a java program on cmd line with an External Jar. I **know that there are plenty of questions about this, BUT after trying the code suggested I get two errors.**\

Its a simple program called "HelloJar.java" and it utilized Apache Commons Lang String Utils.

Error I see (***As you can see I set the classpath and run it***.):

[image: ClassPathError]

Works **fine** in Eclipse though:

[image: EclipseRun]

Folder Structure (In jars is the jar necessary and in Src is the project I need):

[image: FolderStructure]

Here is the **.jar file** that I import for StringUtils:

[image: jar folder]

What does the cannot find symbol mean?

-----------------------After Rajesh's Answer------------------------------------

[image: 2ndError]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is, jar's not set in classpath and results in compilation errors:

As per path shared, command to compile should be :

cd C:\Users\Controlled\Documents\Eclipse_Projects\HelloWorld\src

```
javac -cp .;C:\Users\Controlled\Documents\Eclipse_Projects\HelloWorld\jars\* HelloJar.java
```

Command to run java program with above path:

```
java -cp .;C:\Users\Controlled\Documents\Eclipse_Projects\HelloWorld\jars\* HelloJar
```

Comment: why do you use the "lib?"

Comment: Hey Rajesh, I ran the script and posted the error message I recieve.

Comment: I did and typed "dir" to make sure that the .jar was where I was pointing to.

Comment: So the key thing is I was working with an External Jar AND a .properties file. I needed to refer to the two in different capacities. The .jar needs a simple * while the properties needs another reference. Basically set TWO classpaths.

Answer (score 0):

> What does the cannot find symbol mean?

That means, compiler is unable to find the specified path in the classpath. So, that means, when you are trying to run your jar from command line, your library which has

`org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils`

is not found. So, in order to fix that, please check if the library is included in your jar or if you have that in classpath and specifying the correct classpath.

Comment: I am using commons-lang-2.6.jar

Comment: Is that in classpath?

Comment: I just put *.jar in the classpath

Answer (score 0):

Although you did set your classpath to the correct folder, windows fle path separation is different from a Unix Box.

```
javac -cp ".;./jars/org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.jar/" HelloJar.java 
java -cp ".;./jars/org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.jar/" HelloJar
```

Comment: I added the .jar file that I import to make it work. Am I using the wrong one?

Answer (score 0):

Another Java distinction is that the classpath is the compile-time path.  It is not the same as the execution-time path.